# Make an image jump IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, image, cocoa-touch

I need the image to to up the screen like 15 units, slow down (not an immediate stop), then come back down. I am very new to this and dont know what to do. I hope someone can help. Let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use 2 path: CABasicAnimation  or UIView animation (in code difference not great). UIView more simple and better for simple animation. CAAnimation needs in Quartz framework and also has more lower preferences. This two guides will help http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial , http://www.raywenderlich.com/5478/uiview-animation-tutorial-practical-recipes

Using CAAnimation simple (as example):

```
-(void)animationRotation
 {
      CABasicAnimation *anim;
      anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
      anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];  // this what you need - slow down (not an immediate stop)
     anim.duration = 0.5;
     anim.repeatCount = 1;

      anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
      [anim setDelegate:self];    

      anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(15)];
      [myView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"transform"];

      CGAffineTransform rot = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(15.0);
       myView.transform = rot;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You take the UIImageView that contains the image and animate upwards with `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`. In the animation block you just change the `frame` of your image view.

In `options` you use `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut` going up.

Once completed you immediately start a second animation this time using `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn`. Thus

```
NSTimeInterval durationUp = 1.5;
[UIView animateWithDuration:durationUp delay:0.0 
   options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut 
   animations:^{
      CGRect f = imageView.frame;
      f.origin.y += 15;
      imageView.frame = f;
   }
   completion:nil];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:durationUp 
   options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn 
   animations:^{
      CGRect f = imageView.frame;
      f.origin.y -= 15;
      imageView.frame = f;
   }
   completion:nil];
```

Comment: The image goes up very fast and comes down very slow. How can I make it jump up slower but fall down a little faster. I would love to approve if you can help with that.

Comment: Try fiddling with the duration times.

Comment: I have for some reason I cant get the fist part of the animation to work. It always just teleports up